# strtotime date weird result

Tags: php, date

Given the following string date: `Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

in php if I do a strtotime on the above, and then convert it back to a string date, it seems to gain an hour.

```
echo $str_date,"  Vs ",date("c",strtotime($str_date));
```

Produces:

`Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` Vs `2011-09-02T22:00:00+01:00`

I realise this is to do with daylight savings, but how does one compensate for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realise this is to do with daylight savings, but how does one compensate for this?

By not using `date()` and `strtotime()`; the `DateTime` class is preferred.

```
$str_date = 'Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100';
$datetime = new DateTime($str_date);
echo $datetime->format('c'); // 2011-09-02T21:00:00+01:00
```

or in procedural style

```
$str_date = 'Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100';
echo date_format(date_create($str_date), 'c'); // 2011-09-02T21:00:00+01:00
```

---

Aside: if you wish to still use `date()`/`strtotime()` then, as the other answers and your own observations show, you need to be careful with the time zones in use in the date string and your script.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstanding,
there is not day light saving in this case,
BUT **GMT**, you gain one hour because of that

in my timezone (GMT+8)

```
php -r "echo date('r', strtotime('Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100'));"
Sat, 03 Sep 2011 04:00:00 +0800
```

which I gain 7 hours, due to `GMT+8 - GMT+1 = 7`

Answer (score 1):

Which PHP version do you use? What is your `date.timezone` setting? I'm asking because I cannot reproduce your output running PHP 5.3.6 on Mac OS X:

```
$str_date   = 'Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100  (GMT Daylight Time)';
echo $str_date,"  Vs ",date("c",strtotime($str_date));
// Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100  (GMT Daylight Time)  Vs 1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00
```

This is correct because `Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` is not a valid date/time string.

```
$str_date   = 'Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100';
echo $str_date,"  Vs ",date("c",strtotime($str_date));
// Fri Sep 02 2011 21:00:00 GMT+0100  Vs 2011-09-02T22:00:00+02:00
```

This is correct because I'm in GMT+2.

Comment: yup, `(GMT Daylight Time)` is superfluous

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `strtotime()` renders your time as SOAP format: `YY "-" MM "-" DD "T" HH ":" II ":" SS frac tzcorrection?`

result is:

```
"2008-07-01T22:35:17.02", "2008-07-01T22:35:17.03+08:00"
```

You can try to format your time string as some other time format. Look in http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php